# Groups and quantifiers {m,n}

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, regex-group, quantifiers

Is it possible to use quantifiers with groups?

For example. I want to match something like:

- 11%
- 09%
- aa%
- zy%
- g1%
- 8b%
  ...

The pattern is: 2 letters or numbers (mixed, or not) and a % ending the string ...

```
<?php
echo preg_match('~^([a-z]+[0-9]+){2}%$~', 'a1%'); // 0, I expect 1.
```

I know, this example doesn't make too much sense. A simple [list]{m,n} would solve this one. It's as simples as possible just to get an answer.

Comment: I don't think that regular expression matches what you want it to match.  That regular expression matches one or more letters, followed by one or more numbers, *twice*, then a % and the end of the string.  So `a1a1%` would match.  I think what you meant to write is `/^([a-z]|[0-9]){2}%$/`.  Which will match the string you gave, as well as being an example for your desire to use quantifiers with groups (which is totally legit, as per @jerry 's response).

Answer (score 1):

You sure can apply quantifiers to groups. For example, I have the string:

```
HouseCatMouseDog
```

And I have the regex:

```
(Mouse|Cat|Dog){n}
```

Where `n` is any number. You can play around changing the value of `n` [here](http://www.regex101.com/r/iO2pY7).

As for your example (yes, `[list]{m,n}` would be simpler), it will work only if there is an alphabet or more, followed by a number, or more. As such, only `g1` will match.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need use 2 characters classes, only one would do your job.

```
echo preg_match('~^([a-z0-9]{2})%$~', 'a1%');
```

**RegExp meaning**

```
^ => It will match at beggining of the string/line
(
    [a-z0-9] => Will match every single character that match a-z(abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz) class and 0-9(0123456789) class.
    {2} => rule above must be true 2 times
) => Capture block
% => that character must be matched after a-z and 0-9 classes
$ => end of string/line
```

Comment: Following this example it MUST start with a letter. Thanks.

Comment: @ThomThomThom It can start with a number. Character classes don't look at the order of characters within them. In the regex above, you can have a situation where there are no letters at all, and it will still match.